# What is the best modeling methodology for representing software system?

Tags: architecture, modeling, representation

What is the best modeling methodology for representing software system. I mean like UML and so on.
Is UML better or is there something  better than that out there?
My need is to represent graphically my web application , which is a 3-tier architecture.
I need a engineering model methodology like UML to depict the entire software system
from the front end portal to middleware EAI to the database.

What is out there for such a thing?
Please do not close this question , not related to programming but software.
So a request to the SO community . Do not close this question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You might wanna take a look at ArchiMate - http://www.archimate.org/

Comment: is it effective and does it add value in the communication?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use any formal modelling language at all, instead merging bits from UML, flowcharts and doodles together with a brief description of what is happening.

Although the ideals of UML is to provide a common unambiguous interpretation of what is going on, I've found that in practice one needs to provide a description alongside - either verbally or otherwise.

My two cents...

Answer (score 0):

UML should work. MS Visio is a decent tool to create the models. You can write descriptions on the Visio UML diagrams as well.

A tool or modeling language can never compensate for a bad design! Simpler and elegant the design, lesser the dependency on tool or language.

Comment: I m not looking for design at the moment, just the overall architecture for the application.